# Console window closes abruptly while using windows task schedular to run Python script

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-3.5, windows-console

I have written some Python code to automate a task. Then I scheduled the Python script to execute twice a week using windows task scheduler. The task runs but there are two issues.

The console prints some error. It is strange because when I run the script manually after opening command prompt everything works as expected. This is what I do manually.

```
cd directory
directory>script.py
```

Inside the task scheduler I have directly specified the location of the script to run as `C:\full\path\to\script.py`

Second issue is that I can't even diagnose the error because the console closes as soon as it executes the script. This is despite the fact that I have added a dummy input command at the end of script like this:

```
All my Python code
input('Press any key to exit')
```

I also tried to keep the console open by using `time.sleep(60)` after importing the `time` module.

Can anyone tell me how can I keep the console open. Let me repeat that I am running the script using windows task scheduler. Running the script manually generates no error.

Thanks.

Comment: try "python script.py" instead of "script.py"

Comment: Where should I try it? Do I need to edit the path of my script in task scheduler?

Comment: Create a test task: `schtasks /create /tn pytest /tr "C:\full\path\to\script.py" /sc once /st 00:00 /sd 01/01/1900`. Then run it manually: `schtasks /run /tn pytest`. Does it work or flash a console with an error?

Comment: @eryksun I am sorry, I don't follow. :). I used the GUI program that windows comes with to create my scheduled task. Since, you are doing it all by typing commands. I don't fully understand it. Do I have to type all of `schtasks ... /1900` inside command prompt?

Comment: In the command you wrote, I guess `/tn` is task name, `/tr` is task diretory ans so on. Why is the date set to be `01/01/1900`? Thanks.

Comment: I typed it in command prompt (with administrative privileges) but the console just flashes, it was supposed to open up my browser window and prompt me for input which it does while running the task normally. :)

Comment: /tr is the command line for the task to run. /st is the start time. /sd is the start date. They don't matter for this test, so I set the date to way in the past. /sc is the schedule, which is set to "once", but it will never run by the schedule anyway. It only runs manually via /run.

Comment: Try changing it to use `/tr "py.exe 'C:\full\path\to\script.py'"`. Note that the whole commandline is in double quotes, and the script path is in single quotes.

Comment: This time the task ran but there was the same error that appeared earlier when I used task scheduler to create the task. I just could not read it because it disappeared very quickly. Is there some way to stall the script to see what the error is? I have already tried the two methods I mentioned.  Should I add a `while` loop in the end that always computes to `true`?

Comment: If the error is from Python try using the -i flag to force an interactive shell: `/tr "py.exe -i 'C:\full\path\to\script.py'"`

Comment: Nothing opened up this time. Is it `-i 'C:\ ` (with spaces) or `-i'C:\ ` (without spaces)? When I run the file using command prompt manually, it shows no error. Is it still possible that there would be some error when the command run through the task scheduler?

Comment: If your script naively depends on the working directory being the script directory, then it won't work when run from the task scheduler unless you set the working directory in the task. This can't be set using schtasks from the command line, at least not without XML. Or you can run a .lnk shortcut that sets the working directory. But really a script should never depend on the working directory to find its configuration and data files. They should be relative to the script for read-only data or in a private `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or `%APPDATA%` subdirectory.

Comment: Yes, my script modifies a text file inside some folder one level above it. Is that still called dependence?

Comment: @NeenaVivek, you can't depend on the working directory for that. Start from the script directory: `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`. (Stack Overflow usage note: notify a user about a comment by including the user name prefixed by @. It's not necessary when messaging the creator of a question or answer, but for everyone else you can't depend on SO to figure out who to notify. I wasn't notified about your comment, else I would have replied sooner.)

Comment: @eryksun I thought everyone is notified once they are part of a discussion. I don't fully understand what your statement meant. Do I need to replace `the_file = 'templates/functions.txt'` with `the_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`? where `the_file` gives the location of the file I am working on? Thanks for being so patient. :)

Comment: The path `templates/functions.txt` depends on the process working directory. But `templates` is in the script directory. If you have `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`, then manually create the fully qualified path as follows: `the_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'templates', 'functions.txt')`. You could also call `os.chdir(script_dir)` to set the working directory and continue using a relative path, but that doesn't scale to multi-threaded programs that may depend on files in other directories. Concurrently modifying the working directory is unsafe.

Comment: @eryksun thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I missed the notification so could not respond earlier. Sorry :) Do I need to supply `sys.argv[0]`? How will it be set?

Comment: Python sets `sys.argv` from parsing the command line. You can count on `sys.argv[0]` being the script's path relative to the initial working directory. Immediately get the `dirname()` and convert it to an `abspath()`, i.e. a fully qualified path. If you're writing a package with other modules, the path for each module should be in its `__file__` global variable.

Comment: @eryksun I tried it today and the code worked. I used `os.chdir(script_dir)` because it seemed simple and I only need to work in that directory. If you write it as an answer, I will happily accept it. :)